# $\mathcal{V}$ attains a minimum

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be convex, continuous and s.t. $\exists\, p \in (1,\infty), \delta >0$ with $V(t) \geq \delta \lvert t \rvert^p, \; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus (-1,1)$. Let
$$M := \{ \rho \in L^p[0,1]: \rho \geq 0 \text{ on } [0,1] \text{ and } \int_0^1 \rho(x) \;\mathrm{d}x = 1 \}$$
and define
$$\mathcal{V}(\rho) = \int_0^1 V(\rho(x)) \; \mathrm{d}x \in [0,\infty], \; \rho \in L^p[0,1].$$

Why does $\mathcal{V}(\rho)$ attains a minimum on $M$ if we know that $\mathcal{V}$ is convex, lower semi-continuous and $M$ is weakly closed and convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{V}$ is convex and attains no negative values, for every $c\in [0,\infty)$ the set $S_c = \mathcal{V}^{-1}([0,c])$ is convex. Since $\mathcal{V}$ is lower semicontinuous, $S_c$ is closed. Since

$$\mathcal{V}(\rho) = \int_0^1 V(\rho(x))\,dx \geqslant \int_{\{x : \lvert \rho(x)\rvert \geqslant 1\}} V(\rho(x))\,dx \geqslant \delta\int_{\{x : \lvert \rho(x)\rvert \geqslant 1\}} \lvert \rho(x)\rvert^p\,dx \geqslant \delta(\lVert\rho\rVert_p^p - 1),$$

$S_c$ is bounded. So $S_c$ is closed convex and bounded, hence weakly compact. Then $S_c \cap M$ is also weakly compact, and

$$S := \bigcap_{c > \inf \{\mathcal{V}(\rho) : \rho \in M\}} (M\cap S_c)$$

is an intersection of nonempty weakly compact sets with the finite intersection property. Hence $S\neq \varnothing$.

Comment: What does $S \neq \varnothing$ implies?

Comment: $S$ is the set of $\rho \in M$ with $\mathcal{V}(\rho) \leqslant \inf \{ \mathcal{V}(\varrho) : \varrho\in M\}$. So $S\neq \varnothing$ means the infimum is attained, and hence a minimum.